# Add thread safe method to listBox

Tags: c#, thread-safety, extension-methods

I have a thread and want to update a list with the progress, but form control arent thread safe. So I learn how solve with this [**article**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(EHInvalidOperation.WinForms.IllegalCrossThreadCall);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5.2);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true).

The problem is there are many more sources and each source have his own list to display the progress. So how I make every listbox has his own `ThreadSafeSetText()` method to clean the code?

```
delegate void SetTextCallback(string text);
private async void btnRun_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   await Task.Run(() =>
   {
      importSource1();
   });

   //await Task.Run(() =>
   //{
   //   importSource2();
   //});
}

private void importSource1()
{
   // db stuff in a Parallel.For

   SetText("Result");
}

private void SetText(string text)
{
   // InvokeRequired required compares the thread ID of the
   // calling thread to the thread ID of the creating thread.
   // If these threads are different, it returns true.
   if (this.lstImportSource1.InvokeRequired)
   {
      SetTextCallback d = new SetTextCallback(SetText);
      this.Invoke(d, new object[] { text });
   }
   else
   {
      this.lstImportSource1.Items.Insert(0, text);
   }
}
```

Comment: You tagged your question with "extension-methods" so you probably know what are extension methods in C# and how can they help you to solve this problem?

Comment: @Evk Yes, I know something about it, but not my strength. I can check example and add the method. But dont know how assign a delegated inside? Also not sure if will qualify as ThreadSafe.

Comment: You shouldn't be calling `Invoke` like this in the first place.  Update the UI after the `await`, when you're in the UI thread, not from the operation you're running in another thread.

Comment: @Servy You mean I save the `"strResult"` in a global variable and set the listBox when the thread end?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza No, you should return it from the method, rather than relying on global state.

Comment: If you can use "real" `async-await` approach for your `importSource` methods - then you can get rid from threadsafe problem

Comment: @fabio Im new on this can you point me to one example of what "real" mean? Or what is wrong with my approach I tought was doing it ok.

Comment: Maybe you should post more real code so we can help you with real async await. With current code in question it's not easy.

Comment: Based on your example your problem is what you described in the title - "updating UI control from another thread". As you already noticed updating UI controls from another thread requires some kinds of hacks/workarounds, so my advise will be : try to avoid this and design your code where everything which uses UI controls happens on UI thread. Without real code of `ImportSource` it difficult to provide useful example about `async-await`

Comment: @Fabio The `importSource` do some db storeprocedures using `parallel.For` and the final result is show in the list as a log.

Comment: @Evk What was wrong with your deleted answer?

Comment: Nothing wrong, just thought it is better to use async await correctly (since you already use it, but wrong) than dispatching to UI thread manually. But you can use my answer still if you want - it is valid.

Comment: @evk Can you elaborated what Im doing wrong? I can send back the result, but the problem is for the `parallel.For`, would be messy create a structure for each result.

Comment: I cannot tell what exactly you are doing wrong because you posted very rudimentary code which does nothing useful (and part with Parallel.For is mentioned like this > "db stuff in a Parallel.For"). Signs of you are doing something wrong are: 1. await Task.Run(...) < almost always wrong. 2. Parallel.For does not play well with async\await. How to use async\await correctly is shown in Fabio answer (and also how to execute things in parallel in that case). I would like to help you more, but it is MUCH easier to do with more code of how you are going it now.

Comment: @evk Isnt `Parallel.For` I change it for `Parallel.ForEach()`. I use a more complex version of this [**answer**](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/155263/95510)  The thing is In the `body` section I want print what ranges are alreadt done in a `ListBox` to show the progress. Also some of the ranges sometimes return error, so also want to print the errors in a different list. So if I follow Fabio suggestion would need to keep all result in some kind of list and print only when the process end.

Comment: Right now I'm using Background workers to start the `Parallel.ForEach()` each minute, but read in [**stephen blog**](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/05/taskrun-vs-backgroundworker-round-1.html) Task.Run() is a better option.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comment that `ImportSource` is a method which executes database procedures, my suggestion use `async-await` aproach.
`Async-await` was designed for more effective resource usage when your code executes operations which "touches" external resources (database, file system, web api etc).

Because during execution of database query(for example) your method "do nothing", it only send request and wait for the response. Creating new thread which "do nothing" considered as wasting resources.

With `async-await` operation will be executed on one thread(most of the time) where you can simply use UI controls.

You can create own asynchronous method for every procedure

```cs
public async Task ExecuteProcedure1Async()
{
    using (var connection = new SqlConnection("connection string"))
    using (var command = new SqlCommand("dbo.sqlProcedure1", connection))
    {
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        // Here execution will send request to the database
        // and be returned to the caller of this method         
        await connection.OpenAsync();
        // Continue after OpenAsync is completes and
        // Here execution will again will be returned to the caller 
        await command.ExecuteCommandAsync();
        // Continues after ExecuteCommandAsync is completed
    }      
}
```

Similar methods can be created for another stored procedures

Below all procedures will executes "almost" simultaneously.
Because we will send requests without waiting for responses
and wait only when all procedures completes

```cs
private async Task ImportSource1Async()
{
    // Because asynchronoud method returns Task
    // We can create collection of tasks and "await" them all
    // after they have been started
    var tasks = new[] 
    {
        ExecuteProcedure1Async(),
        ExecuteProcedure2Async(),
        ExecuteProcedure3Async()
    };

    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}
```

Then you can combine all `ImportSourceAsync` methods together in the `button_click` eventhandler and use UI controls.

```cs
private async void btnRun_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await ImportSource1Async();
    lstImportSource1.Items.Insert(0, "Import source 1 complete");

    await ImportSource2Async();
    lstImportSource1.Items.Insert(0, "Import source 2 complete");

    await ImportSource3Async();
    lstImportSource1.Items.Insert(0, "Import source 3 complete");
}
```

Comment: The problem I see is result text need things from the process, like `startTime, rowsProcess, totalTime`, Also in case of errors, I have a different `lstErrror` to log what has happen. But looking to your aproach looks like I should wrap all those in a class and return it from the `ImportSource` function?

Comment: You can change `ImportSource1Async` to return a data with results of import process. In "dirty" way you can update UI controls inside `ImportSourceAsync` - in this case whole execution will hapenned on UI thread